# Get all applications in Podio

Tags: podio

I would like to  get all apps which are accessible to me. So I used the API 
https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-all-apps-5902728

There is a 'limit' parameter but there is no 'offset' parameter.
The max value of limit is 100. 
Is there any other method to get all apps?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can still go through hierarchy Org => Space => App => Item

1. Get all organisations, which will also give all spaces
   https://developers.podio.com/doc/organizations/get-organizations-22344
2. Get all apps per space
   https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-apps-by-space-22478

Small example in **Ruby** demonstrating how it works

```
  orgs = Podio::Organization.find_all()
  orgs.each do |org|
    org.spaces.each do |space|
      puts "Working in space id:#{space['space_id']} name:'#{space['name']}'"
      apps = Podio::Application.find_all_for_space(space['space_id'])
      apps.each do |app|
       puts "\tApp id:#{app['app_id']} name:'#{app['config']['name']}'"
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Then If I have 50 workspaces, I need to use 50 API calls to get all the apps, right? Then why Podio have https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-all-apps-5902728 this API call?

Comment: You can use `Podio::Application.find_all_for_current_user` call to get list of apps with needed name.  For example: `apps_v2 = Podio::Application.find_all_for_current_user(:text => 'Bug')` will return all `Bug` apps from different workspaces.